# latest aws xgb image does not support reg:

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

The following code snippet is inspired by [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html).

```
hyperparameters = {
        "max_depth":"5",
        "eta":"0.2",
        "gamma":"4",
        "min_child_weight":"6",
        "subsample":"0.7",
        "objective":"reg:squarederror",
        "num_round":"10"}

output_path = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(s3_bucket_name, s3_prefix)

estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(image_uri=sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region_name, "1.2-2"), 
                                          hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                                          role=role,
                                          instance_count=1, 
                                          instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge', 
                                          volume_size=1, # 1 GB 
                                          output_path=output_path)

estimator.fit({'train': s3_input_train, 'validation': s3_input_val})
```

It works fine. I was trying to use:

```
training_image_name = image_uris.retrieve(framework='xgboost', region=region_name, version='latest')
```

instead of:

```
sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region_name, "1.2-2")
```

to (I believe) get hold of the latest training image but reg:squarederror is not supported? Is my code to get hold of the latest image name incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "latest" it not suggested as per documentation(see note): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html

Use specific versions as they are more stable.

Comment: So I would need to look at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ecr-eu-west-2.html#xgboost-eu-west-2.title

and pick the latest, which is 1.5-1 at the moment?

Comment: Yes. You need to do that.